# Connect Dell XPS13 9360 via Thunderbolt3/USB-C to a DP monitor

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, dell

I have XPS 9360 with Ubuntu pre installed and a monitor with display port.

I wanted now to use daisy chaining with the Laptop, however, the adapter I bought does not work, so the Dell support sent me a link to an adapter I could use which said it's only compatible with Windows. When I asked him about it, he told me that Ubuntu currently doesn't support USB-C/Thunderbolt 3.

Is this true? Do I not have any option to connect my XPS13 9360 Developer Edition with Ubuntu to an external monitor?

Kernel is `4.4.0-57-generic` btw.

Comment: I am looking forward to buy a xps13 but I am really afraid the external display doesn't work. I found a video where it shows it working with Linux: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K645WWl0Ff4 

I am also evaluating picking a latitude 7000 13.3 which is the "business" version of xps13 but with an hdmi in addition. 

Have you managed to make it work? Please share with us!

Comment: Hi. The guy from the Dell support "lied" or was simply uninformed. It was no problem to connect the laptop via daisy chaning to multiple monitors. But I wouldn't use Ubuntu with Unity tbh. Either use Ubuntu 17.10 or use sth. else using Gnome. Unity is just way too buggy

Answer (score 1):

My Dell based laptop powers two external displays, one via HDMI the other via Thunderbolt 3 Displayport with an external [USB-C to HDMI converter](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01M6C49X2/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

Contrary to other advise it works perfectly in Ubuntu 16.04 with Intel HD530 graphics (Sky Lake i7 6700HQ). nVidia drives the HDMI port:

[image: nVidia X-Server Settings]